# ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface

Tags: networking, gnome, software-installation, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu 20.4.2 LTS.

```
     $ sudo snap install chromium

     INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
     error: cannot perform the following tasks:
     - Buscar e verificar asserções para o snap "gnome-3-28-1804" (145) (persistent network error: Get    https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-revision/hHBPyo_1mDxJyElepXvzRzMh9z1va7oAgyEb61sSdOJEz0s3Rh4jUTT7_wI8Z3Uw?max-format=0: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft
    .io: Temporary failure in name resolution)


    $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
    
    $ sudo snap install chromium

    snap "chromium" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

   $ chromium

   ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface.
```

I have no idea what is that. From the litle I know, looks like my browser is running in someone server.

Someone is running chromium in other machine? What I can do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation of `gnome-3-28-1804` worked for me

```
snap remove gnome-3-28-1804
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
```

Comment: I had the same error running Spotify and this fixed it. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and got the exact same error message citing `gnome-3-28-1804`, but there is no `gnome-3-28-1804` available according to `snap search`.

Comment: I had a similar error just trying to run snap-store.  The package was gnome-3-38-2004.  I ended up uninstalling the snap-store package and some dependencies and then reinstalling them to get things working again.

Comment: was stuck forever at: Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "skype"  . your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
snap connect chromium:gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-28-1804:gnome-3-28-1804
```

*P.S: you might need to wait a couple of seconds on the first launch...*