# Spotify client gives error "not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface"

Tags: gnome, spotify

I have two separate machines, both running Ubuntu 22.04.  On both, when I try to open the Spotify client for Linux, it returns only the error "not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface".  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1337374) recommends installing the snap `gnome-3-28-1804` for such an error.  The problem is that this snap does not exist for 22.04 systems.  Even assuming that `1804` represents the version number, there is nothing in `snap search` that is of the form `gnome-X-Y-(18|20|22)04` that might correspond to an updated version of this snap.

Spotify doesn't support this client, so there's no info from them.  Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot and correct this?

**Update** Spotify now works on the other machine, despite that fact that, like all Ubuntu 22.04 machines, it does not have access to `gnome-3-28-1804`.  I did nothing that I know of to cause it to work.  Both machines are using the same version of the Spotify snap, `1.2.8.923.g4f94bf0d`, so the problem must be something specific to this Ubuntu 22.04 system, not the app.

**Update 2** I gave up and uninstalled the app, then reinstalled it.  Spotify opens, question is now moot.